# How to use LSTM to predict values from a different range than it was trained on

Tags: keras, lstm

I try to train a simple LSTM to predict the next number in a sequence (1,2,3,4,5 --> 6).

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [[[(j+i)/100] for j in range(5)] for i in range(100)]
ys = [(i+5)/100 for i in range(100)]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xs, ys)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(5,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

training = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=200)

new_xs = np.array(xs)*5
new_ys = np.array(ys)*5
pred = model.predict(new_xs)
plt.scatter(range(len(pred)), pred, c='r')
plt.scatter(range(len(new_ys)), new_ys, c='b')
```

In order for the net to learn anything I had to normalize the training data (divided it by 100). It did work indeed for the data from the range it was trained on.

I want it to be able to predict the numbers form outside the range it was trained on, but as soon as it leaves the range, it starts to diverge:

[image]

When I increased the number of units in both LSTM layers to 30 it looks a little better, but it's still diverging:

[image]

Is LSTM capable of learning that task without adding an infinite number of units?

Comment: Any reason to use two LSTMs here?

Comment: @gidim not really. I was just playing around with LSTMs and decided to try to predict outside the original range

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same question, and I came across [the following paper from 2019](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.05672.pdf) and the [corresponding Git repo](https://github.com/nla-group/ABBA-LSTM). In particular, see section 5.3 in the paper. It seems like ABBA-LSTM is the solution, though it depends on the time series problem you're trying to solve.